# CustomID auto-generated at time of Insert Query: How get it before inserting

Tags: java, mysql, database, database-design

I am using the below mysql function which triggers auto generated customeID at the time of insert query.Now the requirement has i need the ID before inserting, at the same time maintaining uniqueness.

```
DELIMITER $$
 CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` FUNCTION `getNextCustomSeq`(
sSeqName VARCHAR(50),
sSeqGroup VARCHAR(10)
) RETURNS varchar(20) CHARSET latin1
 BEGIN
DECLARE nLast_val INT; 

SET nLast_val =  (SELECT seq_val
                      FROM _sequence
                      WHERE seq_name = sSeqName
                            AND seq_group = sSeqGroup);
IF nLast_val IS NULL THEN
    SET nLast_val = 1;
    INSERT INTO _sequence (seq_name,seq_group,seq_val)
    VALUES (sSeqName,sSeqGroup,nLast_Val);
ELSE
    SET nLast_val = nLast_val + 1;
    UPDATE _sequence SET seq_val = nLast_val
    WHERE seq_name = sSeqName AND seq_group = sSeqGroup;
END IF; 

SET @ret = (SELECT concat(sSeqGroup,'-',lpad(nLast_val,6,'0')));
RETURN @ret;
 END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

This is how i trigger the sequence using java

```
public static void setTriggerForIDgeneration(String course_name){
    String dropquery="DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS custom_autonums_bi";
    PropertyFileReader propreader = new PropertyFileReader();
    String courseName = course_name.replace(" ", "_");
    String[] sequence =courseName.split("_");
    String squenceName =sequence[0];
    Connection conn = DatabaseConnectionUtils.getJdbcDBConnection();
    try {
        Properties prop = propreader.getPropertFileReader();
        String trigger_query   =prop.getProperty("Trigger_squence_on_table");
        String final_query = trigger_query.replace("default",courseName).replace("sequence_with", squenceName);
        Statement stmnt =conn.createStatement();
        stmnt.addBatch(dropquery);
        stmnt.addBatch(final_query);
        int[] rowaffected = stmnt.executeBatch();
        System.out.println("AutoID generation triggerd for New   Course................... "+rowaffected);
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Query to trigger the function :

```
CREATE TRIGGER custom_autonums_bi BEFORE INSERT ON XXXXX FOR each ROW         BEGIN SET NEW.XXXID = getNextCustomSeq("XXXID","sequence_with"); END
```

Is there any way to get ID before hand

Comment: Your entire stored procedure looks like it can be replaced with a single INSERT ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE statement

Comment: @e4c5 I am sorry  I didn't get you? will this be helping in getting the generated customID before inserting into the database?.

Comment: Your question isn't very clear so I can't answer that comment. But do look up INSERT ON DUPLICATE KEY and you will realize what I am saying.